# Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <> in Column. Expected Int64

Tags: c#

here i am trying to get the comma separated values. In the following code "tbl"
is the table which contains the comma separated values..

```
 private static DataTable PivotFieldData(DataTable tbl)
    {
        var tblPivot = new DataTable();
        if (tbl.Columns.Count > 0)
        {
            tblPivot.Columns.Add(tbl.Columns[0].ColumnName, typeof(int));
            for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                tblPivot.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(tbl.Rows[i][1]), typeof(long));
            }
            var r = tblPivot.NewRow();
            r[0] = tbl.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            for (int col = 0; col < tbl.Rows.Count; col++)
            {
                r[col + 1] = tbl.Rows[col][2].ToString();
            }
            tblPivot.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        return tblPivot;
    }
```

but i am getting an error as follow.

[image: this is the error displayed when i am displaying the table values in a gridview format as]

i have tried like

```
r[col + 1] = tbl.Rows[col][2].ToString().Trim() == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(tbl.Rows[col][2].ToString());
```

but i am getting an error that input string was not in correct format ....
please check it and help me... thank you..

Comment: What  do you mean by `but not the structure`? How do you image an unstructured datatable?

Comment: The number in your exception is less than `int.MinValue`. Change your line where it makes that reference, and use `long` instead.

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward. You can't parse a comma separated list of values with `Int64.Parse`. It expects a *single* value in the string you pass to it, otherwise what do you expect it to do with the rest? You need to split the string and parse each individual value.

Comment: thank you @MattBurland.. can you help me with the correct line of code..

Comment: @krillgar thank you..

Comment: Since it's not really clear what you are actually trying to do. No, not really.

Comment: @MattBurland i am trying to get the comma separated values.. i have changed the value as a comma separated by using the following 

FieldValue = string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN", true),"{0:n}", (t1.FieldValue - t2.PaymentReceived))
say suppose t1.fieldvalue and t2.paymentreceived are two long type values....

if i use this code i am getting the above error that i mentioned in the image..

if this is not the correct format to do.. please suggest me another 

thank you......

Answer (score 4):

The error message is pretty clear. You have a string value (i.e. -2312,77,845.00) and you're trying to store that into a column that is `typeof(long)`. If that string value represents a number then strip out the commas and remove the `ToString` call inside your loop. If it represents a string (which it seems it does because the columns are in the wrong place for it to be a number) then change the column type.

Comment: thank you. and could you please get me an example... @Craig W.

Comment: Since you haven't told me which case is the correct one, then no I can't provide an example. It's really a very simple fix, but first you need to understand your business rules and what it is you're trying to do.